# Blackberry - Disable Save option in BasicEditField?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

I am using a basiceditfield to take input from the user to do some simple string search. But if i type a few letters and wish to go back without continuing the search, it automatically asks me whether to save the contents of the field. I don want this to happen. Can i in any way disable the "Changes made!-save-discard-cancel" option in basiceditfield(or any editfield for that matter)????please help!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this to your MainScreen class:

```
protected boolean onSavePrompt() {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to override the dirty state logic on your Screen class like this:

```
public boolean isDirty() { return false; }
```

Of course you can also just override that same method on a subclass of your Field, and that too should probably work.  (assuming you still want to do dirty-state-tracking of other fields on the screen.)

Answer (score 1):

modify onClose method of Screen

```
 public boolean onClose() {
   this.close();
   return true;
}
```