# How could i avoid the SAVE dialog in my custom blackberry Application?

Tags: blackberry, user-interface, modal-dialog, custom-application

I am writing a blackberry application and pushing screens one after another(three in series)

Screen1 displays Screen2 and Screen2 displays Screen3

When i press "Back Key" on my Blackberry Device i.e., bold 9700, its prompts a dialog box with Question mark image and buttons "Save" "Discard" "Cancel".

Why does this dialog appears?
How can i avoid this dialog?

Please Help
Thanks
SIA

Comment: This is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461403/blackberry-disable-save-option-in-basiceditfield)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blackberry - Disable Save option in BasicEditField ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461403/blackberry-disable-save-option-in-basiceditfield)

Comment: It might be a duplicate, but it's clearer and more useful than the one it's a duplicate of...

Answer (score 1):

you can avoid this type of dialog by overriding onClose method for that screen :

```
public boolean onClose() 
{

  this.close();
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Override the isDirty() method of your Screen (via: [Blackberry - Disable Save option in BasicEditField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461403/blackberry-disable-save-option-in-basiceditfield/2462285#2462285)):

   `public boolean isDirty() { return false; }`
2. You can also override the onSavePrompt() method of your Screen (also via: [Blackberry - Disable Save option in BasicEditField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461403/blackberry-disable-save-option-in-basiceditfield/2461453#2461453)):

   `protected boolean onSavePrompt() { return true; }`

Answer (score 0):

Simply Write this code in your specified class:

```
 protected boolean onSavePrompt() 
   {
       return true;
   }
```

It will disable the Save Prompt Dialog Box.